# How to fine control multiple threads in a Java Application?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am writing a Java Application that aims to get and persist messages in real time. Beyond that, my application should care about several non-functional requirements like lineage control, transaction control, security, logging, monitoring, and so on.

Each feature is defined as a module and will be controlled within a thread concurring to my hardware resources (disk, memory, CPU, and GPU). As consequence, each time my application evolves, my thread control should evolves too.

To deal with that I am creating a global `ExecutorService` to manage all threads in my application. Some of these threads are permanent and defined as `daemon`. My application also control multiple sources. Each one representing a set of all features described above, evolving arbitrarily.

Which are the best practices for that scenery? How to control multiple threads while some will be created and dropped arbitrarily (as daemon or not) and another ones will be executed regularly nested or not to another threads?

Comment: Thank you, Solomon Slow. My application has multiple sources, each one requiring multiple threads to control the data flow. It also requires monitoring and data lineage, for example. The issues is that my application will grow for thousands sources. Of course I will increase my hardware (memory, disck, CPU), but I need to at least improve my fine control about my threads to use my resources properly.

Comment: One rule is don't submit radically differently-sized tasks to the same executor.

Comment: Thank you, Nathan Hughes. I will consider that on my solution. Thank you again!

Comment: In general, thread pool very good, app-lifetime dedicated threads OK,  continual create/terminate/destroy utterly disastrous.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you do not want to manage creation and disposal of threads, use a thread pool (you can create one with `ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);`).

However, be careful of **premature optimisation** (i.e. spending effort "optimising" code, at the expense of readability/maintainability, often when the performance gain is irrelevant). General good practice is:

- Write clean, readable code.
- Run your code and see if you encounter performance issues
- Profile your code (e.g. with JProfiler or JVisualVM) to identify performance issues
- Refactor your code if there is a significant problem with the way it is.

Remember, in general, developer time is more valuable than CPU time. Obviously there are limits to this, but usually you are best served keeping your code clean and readable.

You can also use this process to tweak parameters (e.g. on a fixed thread pool, there are various thresholds that can be fine-tuned to improve performance).